# Do skills, skill points and/or presents carry over another playthrough?

Tags: danganronpa-trigger-happy-havoc

So, when using the monomachine, I get presents used during free time activities, in order to unlock skills or skill points and completing other characters' info

Like, right now, I'm on my first playthrough on Danganronpa Trigger Happy Havoc on Kind difficulty and I'd like to ask if it carries over if I restart the game on Mean difficulty after this playthrough for completing stuff.

**Question**
Do anything I already unlocked or owned in one playthrough carry over another one?

Comment: Are you playing the rerelease [Danganronpa 1.2 Reload](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Danganronpa_1.2_Reload) or the original [Danganronpa Trigger Happy Havoc](http://danganronpa.wikia.com/wiki/Danganronpa:_Trigger_Happy_Havoc)?

Comment: @ChaseIngebritson Trigger Happy Havoc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only carries over on your save file. Once you complete the game if you save in any slot of your choosing, then restart on that save file you can play the game with all of your monocoins, presents and items unlocked in the gallery. I would not recommend doing another playthrough though, the game gives you a way to complete report cards and etc when you finish. You only get the experience of a danganronpa game blind once, so play on a difficulty that will challenge you well enough and enjoy it.

Comment: and I almost thought this question would sink under the numbers and stay lost forever.
I guess you're right for the blind experience, but the Kind difficulty was rather straightforward... (already finished the game FYI)

Comment: ah i have dr as a fave tag i just rarely check this sight nowadays. I made the mistake of doing the medium difficulty in DR1 then played 2 and V3 on Mean mode because honestly you only get that experience once. Also on a side note, would you be kind enough to set my answer as the accepted answer (that green tick thingy).

Comment: I couldn't recall if the courtesy rule was 24 hours after the question has been asked or if it was 24 hours after an answer was posted... but here goes your tick :)